# Unable to install VSCode 1.80 ->. Getting Status code 502 error

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation, redhat

I am trying to install vscode on RHEL 8.2. I download vscode version code-1.80.2-1690491680.el7.x86_64.rpm.

I performed the following command.

*sudo yum localinstall ./code-1.80.1-1689183644.el7.x86_64.rpm --nogpgcheck*

Getting

LOB DIS ORAREVIEW                                                                                           5.8 kB/s | 2.8 kB     00:00
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'dis_orareview':

- Status code: 502 for https://lb-yum-phx.appoci.oraclecorp.com/pditrepos/LOB/DIS/ORAREVIEW/GENERIC/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 10.44.105.53)
  Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'dis_orareview': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried

Any help is much appreciated.

Mustafa

Answer (score 0):

I was able to

I was able to avoid the pditrepos = dis_orareview for this installation and moved beyond.
[acayci@acayci-dev download]$ sudo yum localinstall /scratch/download/code-1.80.2-1690491680.el7.x86_64.rpm --nogpgcheck --disablerepo=dis_orareview